# How can I push the current state and all later commits to another remote, without pushing all the previous commits?

Tags: git, version-control

For a particular project, we would work on an internal repository for convenience, and at regular intervals, zip the entire tree and send it to the client (because they had their own process and wouldn't accept anything else).

We finally managed to convince them to switch to git, with the plan being that their own repository mimics ours (they want their own separate copy of the code for obvious business reasons), and we still `git push origin` as we would otherwise, but also `git push their-remote` from time to time when changes have been approved and we have to make a delivery.

The problem is, we don't want to share the previous 1500 commits with them (partially because of the resulting clutter and partially because we have some pretty... <s>compromising</s> "informal" commit messages). We'd like to keep the history intact in our internal repository, however.

**More precisely,** starting from a stable commit (we'll call "base"), on master, in the recent past, how can we ensure the following :

- Their (currently empty) repository is initialized in a state equivalent to "base", but without all the previous commits.
- We can then commit incremental changes on top of "base", and push those to either our or their remote.
- Our remote still contains the full history (not a requirement)

**Note that :**

- They won't be making any commit of their own. This is really git-as-a-versioning-tool rather than something collaborative.
- We can't just have a "release" branch or something, the entire point is that they, too, can see and switch between the various branches depending on the particular feature set they want / their progress at implementing new changes that break backward compatibility.

We tried various combinations of `--squash`, `--depth 1`, `rebase`, etc. to no avail. But the more I read about it, the more I think we just have a fundamental misunderstanding about the way git works.

**PS :**
One obvious solution would be to start both repositories again from scratch (copy all the files somewhere, start two new repositories, paste them back, then push that "initial commit" to both remotes, and work from there), but we'd like to keep the history (and not completely wreck our environment with a sledgehammer).

Answer (score 0):

git reset --soft commit_hash

git commit -m "next version release"

git push -f origin their_branch

make sure the commit hash you use is your first initial commit, to get rid of all the commit messages.

Answer (score 0):

When you push to a remote branch, it finds all the commits that are reachable from the commit you pushed and which aren't currently resident in the remote's database, and pushes them as well. This is necessary.

That's just how git works. If you have COMMIT but not COMMIT's parents, then you have an invalid repo. git's behavior would then be undefined. What happens if you `git log` on a commit that points to parents which aren't there? It should just explode. I'm pretty sure that what you're asking for is just impossible. I think you have to start over with a fresh repo rooted at BASE. (Keep your old one around - on ice - for posterity.)

You can't even trick git by manually setting BASE's parents to [] on the remote. As soon as you try to do this, BASE's SHA1 will change on the remote and the two repos will no longer have a common ancestor.